# Elasticsearch analyzer like as Netflix

Tags: elasticsearch

I am studying any kinds of analyzers that elasticsearch has.

I am doing tests to do something like Netflix search.

When I am typing in netflix search (after login) the results are returned after each keyup.

I noticed that netflix search the typed lettler in anywhere from film that contain this world.

For instance:
If I type: *"a"*, result=> *A man, Captain America, The Alien...*

Considering that netflix look for **only in title** (in order to facilitate my example), they return even the typed letter is in the middle of the text. like a "Captain America".

Probably they are using "NGram Tokenizer" or are using another analyzed to do this behavior?

I know that "shingle" is good to autocomplete, but does not recognize letter in the middle of the world.

What is the best analyze configuration to make it look like netflix?

Comment: It's all explained here: http://www.unicodeconference.org/presentations/S11T3-Provalov.pdf and https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/global-languages-support-at-netflix-testing-search-queries-ede40f7d93d3 :-)

Comment: @Val, thanks a lot, I could understand the netflix mapping.